# What do you call an answer that disagrees with the question?

Tags: terminology, answers

For example, if person A said "Why should we do x?" and person B said "I don't think we should do x", what would you call this?

Comment: Any reason not to use "disagreement"?

Comment: Are you talking about someone rejecting the underlying assumptions of a question?

Comment: It's not an "answer" to the question in the strict sense, but a rejection of the premise in the (leading) question.

Answer (score 2):

See [What's a frame challenge?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6842/whats-a-frame-challenge) as asked on Stack Exchange *Role-Playing Games* some years ago. From the top answer there...

> *A **frame challenge** is where an author answers a question in a wholly different way the querent never asked for...*

I didn't know that usage myself until relatively recently. Before that, I'd have probably just said...

> [*"**You're asking the wrong question**"*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22You%27re%20asking%20the%20wrong%20question%22)

For OP's *very specific* type of question that the respondent might take issue with...

> [*"**That's a leading question!**"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22That%27s%20a%20leading%20question%22&sca_esv=601135296&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACQVn0-yMso4N4_ezOK5S1IGgsc9AHjVSQ%3A1706119236085&ei=RFCxZcXgBLGshbIPo5W2yAM&ved=0ahUKEwjFkou4zfaDAxUxVkEAHaOKDTkQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22That%27s%20a%20leading%20question%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhsiVGhhdCdzIGEgbGVhZGluZyBxdWVzdGlvbiJI0UZQkApYzj9wAHgAkAEAmAG6AaAB-hiqAQQ5LjE4uAEDyAEA-AEBwgIGECEYChgKiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

...applies when a question has been framed in such a way that it *entails* some background some background context which the respondent doesn't accept. A stereotypical example being...

> [*"**Have you stopped beating your wife yet**?"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Have%20you%20stopped%20beating%20your%20wife%20yet%22)
> *"**Frame challenge! I've never beaten her**!"*

Comment: Is "frame challenge" actually used outside of SE?

Comment: Well, it's certainly an "emerging" usage. As I said above, it's fairly new to me, but there are several post-2000 written instances in Google Books. And there's this piece on [***challenger frame***](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Prime_Time_Activism/kWcoBAVDTLMC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22challenger+frame%22&pg=PA70&printsec=frontcover) from a journalism / political source.

Answer (score 0):

In certain instances, this could be called an "XY problem". The term stems from a situation where someone asks about X, when they really want to know about Y. As an example, if someone asks what kind of toothbrush they should use to paint their house, it's clear what they really want is a painted house (Y), but they are asking about something that isn't really relevant (X). While one could answer the literal question of what toothbrush would be best to paint a house, the more logical response is to reject the premise of the question and recommend a paintbrush instead.

The term doesn't exclusively refer to the answer itself, but more the incongruence of the question and the answer that would actually be useful.

Comment: Is 'XY problem' in common use for such situations (specifically, where a response challenges the validity of the question)?

Answer (score 0):

It can be called a **contradiction** or a **repudiation**.

Cambridge Dictionary has

> [**contradict**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contradict)
> (of people) to say the opposite of what someone else has said, or (of one fact or statement) to be so different from another fact or statement that one of them must be wrong

and

> [**repudiate**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repudiate)
> to refuse to accept something or someone as true, good, or reasonable